# Get all results that match a filter in freebase

Tags: java, freebase

As far as i understood, a freebase query is made by the query (what i'm searching for), plus a filter that should narrow the results of the query.
By the way what i'm trying to accomplish, without success, is returning ALL the matches that are ok for the filter.
For example, I would like to make a query that returns the city that contains a specifical building.

So, supposing I stored the building name in a variable called "buildingName", the filter SHOULD be something like:

```
url.put("filter", "(all type:/location/citytown/postal_code /Commons/architecture/building:\" "+buildingName+"")");
```

But what should i store in the query?

Additional question: is there a way to retrieve the city name from a building or location inside it?